# Horizontal line by header right side

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on my site and i want there to be an horizontal line by the right side of the page headers. Currently this is the code for my header, stripped css.

```
#wrapper #content-holder #main-content #newhead {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: -0x;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
font-family: 'Rokkitt', 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
color: #333;
text-align: left;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: normal;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: -2px;
/*text-transform: uppercase;
border-bottom:1px solid #15A2FF;*/
}
```

Alongside:

```
<div id="newhead"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
```

But for some reason i cant get the lines to show by the side of the header text.

Please help. http://jsbin.com/ILOlivI/1/edit

Comment: What do you mean with "be an horizontal line by the right side of the page headers"? You want a horizontal line vertically aligned with  the middle of the header text that starts a few pixels to the right of the last word in the header and ends on the far right of the screen?

Comment: You should check out the `<hr>` element, which creates a horizontal line and can be manipulated much more easily than a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use a background-image in the header row that is overwritten by a background-color of the text. Something like this:

```
  <div id="newHead"><div>the header text</div></span>

  #newHead {
    background: white url(http://tidesonline.nos.noaa.gov/images/black_line.jpg) center left repeat-x;
  }
  #newHead div {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mVqY6/

This will only work if the text is not too long and if the text is positioned over the background image. In that case you'll need to do some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put in a horizontal line level with the mid-line of the text, border-bottom is not really going to work is it?

Off the top of my head I would be using a single pixel .gif image stretched to 100% of the remaining space and aligned to the middle of the text...  or if you want pixel perfect alignment to a specific text size, use a 1px wide .gif that has your line in it, plus x number of transparent pixels below.

You could introduce an SVG line, or float a DIV beside your text that is half height, with a border top or bottom.  The DIV solution would probably make the most sense if you want to stay in pure CSS/HTML.